# How to properly manipulate a detached Expo app's VCS

Tags: android, git, react-native, expo

I'm programming on Expo for Android and I'm totally new to React-Native and Expo and really can't find something about a detached app's VCS on Expo docs, nor another similar question in the forums or SO (I "detached" my app because I needed [React-Native-signature-capture](https://github.com/RepairShopr/react-native-signature-capture)).

Here are some things to have in mind:

1. We are a team of 2 developers working with the same app.
2. Each one manages his own tasks/issues
3. I'm the one who used to build the Expo app with my own expo account when the app was "attached".

[When I was About to Stage SourceTree showed me this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l43J3.png)

The thing is, when I was about to stage and commmit React-Native code I saw all the **/.expo-source** and **/android** files and all that weights 10MB!... 10mb on a single commit, is that right? Is there something I can do about it? **Do we need those files on VCS?** Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Hi, can you say why you decided to detach?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian I need the library [React-Native-signature-capture](https://github.com/RepairShopr/react-native-signature-capture) (it requires linking the android native code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, those were all necessary files needed for the repo (my fault, I have lots of dependecies) also there were plenty of auto-generated files there (when you do gradle build these files are rebuild each time). So I kept managing the repo like I was doing before the Detach

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the Expo directory anymore. For Android, look at the React Native `.gitignore` [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/local-cli/templates/HelloWorld/_gitignore).

Also check if an `.apk` is trying to make its way into the repo. Add `*.apk` to `.gitignore`.

Comment: I don't know if deleting the Expo directory is the correct solution for this, 10Mb on the repo is not a big deal for us if it doesnt affect the **.apk** size. [similar question in the expo forums](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/740) please, could you check that out?. also there is no apk in VCS